# Blockers not working in hoppers

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image][image][image]I've been creating a pretty large sorting system that uses a ton of hoppers. Part of it is re-naming an item to use as a blocker so that it isn't sorted. I have 3 floors of this, and the first floor and a half it worked beautifully, but suddenly for the rest of them it starts to sort the blockers. I've tried different names, different items, or restarting the game with no success.

Comment: Do you have screenshots and/or a layout of the structure of your setup?

Comment: Yes! I added some pics to the original post. The one of the hopper is how it looks when working correctly, with the last 4 cobblestone now named "cobblestoneg"